# Haskell Type Signature `ThrowsError` vs `Either Error`?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have seen some examples of Haskell code where Either Monad is "hidden" in the type signature using a type constructor. For example:

In some code bases Haskell error handling type signature is written as follows:

```
fooBar :: foo -> Either Error Bar
```

But in some other code base, the very same type signature hides the Either Monad like:

```
type ThrowsError = Either Error

fooBar :: foo -> ThrowsError Bar
```

Is one way better than the other? Where should this be or not be done?

Comment: Like all type aliases, the compiler sees no difference between `Either Error Bar` and `ThrowsError Bar` given that definition of `ThrowsError`. You still construct a value of type `ThrowsError Bar` using `Left` and `Right`. Whether or not to use a type alias is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: My 2 cents: if you use one global error type throughout most of your codebase, then `ThrowsError` encapsulates that nicely. There's one less parameter a human has to read and recognise as "oh that's just the standard error type this codebase uses", and it's well separated from other casual/local uses of `Either`. If your error type isn't always `Error` then you'd have to use `type Throws e = Either e` (or `type Throws = Either`); at that point there's really not a lot of purpose. The API in is still exactly that of `Either`, so it's probably less confusing to just make that clear.